# Script is not working with high performance computer

Tags: python, linux, unix, pbs, supercomputers

I am using Tinaroo (a high-performance computer in University of Queensland)

I built a demo python code (demo1.py), simple that creates a file that has the time of the execution of the code.

```
import datetime

StartTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
print("Start : " + StartTime)
out = "Hello This working at " + StartTime
text_file = open("Result_"  + "_" + StartTime , "w")
n = text_file.write(out)
text_file.close()
```

I tested it, works fine

Now I want to send it as a PBS JOB to the server.

I built this PBS file (simpledemo.pbs)

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -j oe
#PBS -m ae
#PBS -N SimpleDemo
#PBS -o out.log
#PBS -e out.log
#PBS -l walltime=01:00:00
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=1:mem=4GB

shopt -s expand_aliases
source /etc/profile.d/modules.sh
cd ${PBS_O_WORKDIR}
module load python3
python3 demo1.py
```

But it does not execute the python code and I get this `out.log` file

```
########################### Execution Started #############################
JobId:731935.tinmgr2
UserName:asmgx
GroupName:qj
ExecutionHost:tn327a
###############################################################################
/var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/731935.tinmgr2.SC: line 14: python3: command not found
########################### Job Execution History #############################
JobId:731935.tinmgr2
UserName:asmgx
GroupName:qj
JobName:SimpleDemo
SessionId:27100
ResourcesRequested:mem=4gb,ncpus=1,place=free,walltime=01:00:00
ResourcesUsed:cpupercent=100,cput=00:00:05,mem=0kb,ncpus=1,vmem=0kb,walltime=00:00:05
QueueUsed:General
AccountString:qj
ExitStatus:127
###############################################################################
```

And it is clearly getting this error:

```
python3: command not found
```

Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Are you sure `python3` is the correct command name?  And if so, is it in your path?

Comment: i use Python3 all the time, my friend used it on his account and it worked

Comment: This script uses /bin/bash.  Is that your usual shell?  Do you have a path set up for that shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Message error shows that in this script: `/var/spool/pbs/mom_priv/jobs/731935.tinmgr2.SC`, it cannot find command `python3`. You can modify it to `python`, or create a softlink of the real executable `python` and name it as `python3` (and add it to your `PATH` environment variable).

Comment: i am using "module load python3" this suppose to load python3

Comment: The user knows that `python3` cannot be found. Its in the error message. However I would ask yourself if you know enough about their specific PBS compute environment to provide the broader stack overflow community with a "helpful" answer. More likely than not this is a student that will need to help of their professor/administrator to solve this problem and its debatable whether it provides value for the SO community.